# Automatically saving video files to Android SD card

Tags: android, filesize, android-sdcard

We are creating an app for a user who has about 350MB of video clips. Since most (if not all) Android phones won't have that much internal storage, I'm not sure how we are going to make this work. Is there a way to push the video clips onto the SD card when the user downloads the app? If not, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android Market has a 50MB limit for packaged applications, so you have to have your app download the video files after the app is installed. To do that you'll need to ask for permission to write to the phone's external SD card storage in your app's manifest. For that kind of large file size, you may want to make an interface where the user can choose individual files to download. Take a look at some of the podcasting apps to see how they handle downloading large files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have to upload the files to a server somewhere, then ask the user to go download it, right? Is there any other way?

Comment: As far as I know. Unless you want to split the video files into <50MB chunks and release multiple apps. But then the users would need to install 7 or more apps.

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to find a web server to allow users to download the extra content. Do you know of any websites that I could use (preferably free)?